# How can I create a fake Gamepad object?

Tags: javascript, prototype, joystick, gamepad

I need to create an object that behaves in every way like the `Gamepad` objects found in `navigator.getGamepads()`, but presents specific static data rather than data about a real gamepad. How can I create such an object?

```
> navigator.getGamepads()[0]
Gamepad {
  id: "USB Gamepad (Vendor 0079 Product: 0011)",
  index: 0,
  connected: true,
  timestamp: 1234.567890,
  mapping: "",
  axes: [0, 0],
  buttons: [GamepadButton, GamepadButton, GamepadButton, GamepadButton, GamepadButton, GamepadButton], 
  __proto__: Gamepad
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda late, but cooncidentally enough I ran into the same thing.

I wanted to create fake gamepad object for when my script thinks when there is a gamepad connected, but it can't find it.

So here's a simple solution:

```js
function GamepadObject() {
  return { id: "Fake-Gamepad", index: 0, mapping: "", hand: "", connected: true, buttons: [], axes: [], timestamp: 0, pose: GamepadPose, hapticActuators: [] };
}

// Use it like this:
let gamepad = GamepadObject();

console.log(gamepad);

// Object  { id: "Fake-Gamepad", index: 0, … }
```

I copied a real gamepad and made all the variables reset. This way it can get all child objects from the fake gamepad, and not run into any errors.